# Converge in Distribution imply expectation convergence

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_n$ and $X$ random variables in not the same probability space and let $X_n \to X$ in distribution. If $f(x)\leq C(1+x^m)$, for some $C,m>0$ constants, then I have to prove that $\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)]$ converge to $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$. How can I prove it?

The hint is to take the function $g(x)=\min\{L,f(x)\}$ for a constant $L>0$ and then $L\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Hi, evimath, welcome to Math.SE! Thank you for bringing your questions here. Hope you stay around and contribute to the site. It is considered good style to write your comments in LaTeX via MathJaX (please see my changes to your question for examples, you seem to know LaTeX so it should not be a problem to learn :).

Comment: Are there any conditions for the ranges of $X_n$? What if $f(x) = x$ and $X_n = 0$ with probabilty $\frac{n-1}n$ and $n$ with probability $\frac 1n$.